# Create PowerBI Datamart from Azure Analysis Service

Tags: powerbi, datamart

I am trying to create PowerBI Datamart from Azure Analyis service. There is a datamodel available in the Azure Analysis Service and I can connect using URL and Database Name. The datamodel has ~100 tables present in it and relationship also setup. So my question is, if I want to create a PowerBI datamart from the Azure Analyis service datamode, I need to do the Get Data option of PowerBI datamart and connect to Azure Analyis service, select table, select fields 100 time for getting all the tables of Azure Analyis service datamode into my PowerBI datamart? Is there any import function available where I can import all the tables in a single time?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to copy data from AAS into a database?

The reason you find it difficult is that it's an odd thing to do.  The query designer for AAS/SSAS generates MDX queries which are indented to run aggregate queries that return a handful of rows, and are wholly unsuitable for extracting whole tables.  If you try, the queries will just run forever and fail.

It's possible to extract data from AAS/SSAS tabular models, but you *must* use DAX not MDX, and so you need to the Power Query or "Transform Data" window, and use the advanced editor.

Each query to load a table should look like this, eg to load the 'Customer' table:

```
let
  Dax = "evaluate Customer",
  Source = AnalysisServices.Database("asazure://southcentralus.asazure.windows.net/myserver", "mydatabase", [Query=Dax])
in
  Source
```